# return value from generator in py3.2 *and* py3.5

Tags: python, generator, yield, stopiteration

In Python 3.3 and newer, you can return a value from a generator; we use this in Tornado to have functions that call big and slow subprocesses (`translate_part` below) without blocking the main thread, and also without having more than one of the big&slow functions running concurrently:

```
@gen.coroutine
def translate(self, text, lock):
    parts = yield [translate_part(part, lock) for part in splitup(text)]
    retval = "".join(parts)
    return retval
```

To support Python 3.2, we changed it to the uglier, but equivalent:

```
@gen.coroutine
def translate(self, text, lock):
    parts = yield [translate_part(part, lock) for part in splitup(text)]
    retval = "".join(parts)
    raise StopIteration(retval)
```

However, this is (understandably) deprecated after Python 3.5. But how do we support both Python 3.5+ and Python 3.2? It's impossible to do

```
        if sys.version_info.minor<3:
            raise StopIteration(retval)
        else:
            return retval
```

since Python 3.2 raises SyntaxError on "return retval", and of course

```
        try:
            return retval
        except SyntaxError:
            raise StopIteration(retval)
```

doesn't work. Is there a non-ugly solution to this, or do we have to maintain two versions?

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/ claims fixing things to be backwards-compatible is easy, but all their examples are of StopIteration's/return's *without* values.

Comment: Just because `raise StopIteration(retval)` is deprecated and discouraged, doesn't mean it'll stop working anytime soon. Why not just stick with what you have?

Comment: It fails on Travis CI, and the PEP says it's going away.

Comment: Is that because you are running against Python nightlies? You'd only get a deprecationwarning there. Are warnings raising an error perhaps? You could just suppress that warning for the one usage, until Tornado is ready to drop 3.2 support. And frankly, very few projects still support 3.2.

Comment: Aha, that might explain why it errored out. I think while we still have 3.2-users we'll keep two files and conditionally import, then eventually remove the 3.2 file.